# Getting MySQL data after specific date

Tags: mysql

How can I fetch MySQL data after a specific timestamp? What should the query look like?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where TheNameOfTimestampColumn > than the date");
```

Answer (score 136):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TheNameOfTimestampColumn > '2009-01-28 21:00:00'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TheNameOfTimestampColumn > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can select this by :

`select * from table_name where date_column > "2001-01-01 00:00:00"`

or if you need data within certain time frame then you can try using `between` key word such as:

```
select * from table_name where date_column 
between "2018-01-04 00:00:00" and "2018-01-04 11:59:59";
```

Note that date format should be in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a unix timestamp, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TheNameOfTimestampColumn > FROM_UNIXTIME(your_time_stamp_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL `DATE` function like below

For instance, if you want results after 2017-09-05

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp_field) as date FROM stocks_annc WHERE DATE(timestamp_field) >= '2017-09-05'
```

Make sure to wrap the date within single quotation `''`

Hope this helps.